# Having trouble getting preg_match_all to work

Tags: preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm new to regular expressions and really struggling to get it to work.

I'm trying to grab some information from a page that is in between the following html:

`<!--webbot bot="Include" U-Include="/inspections/Restaurants_Avalon.html" TAG="BODY" startspan  --> EVERYTHING IN BETWEEN<!--webbot bot="Include" i-checksum="41417" endspan -->`

I've tried:

```
$pattern = '/<.*?webbot bot=\"Include\" U-Include=\".*?\".*?startspan.*?(.*?)<.*?webbot bot=\"Include\" i-checksum=\".*?\" endspan.*?/i';
```

and a few other dozen variations but my obvious lack of experience and understanding of regular expresses has just created regular messes rather than expressions.

Can someone have a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just change this part :

```
startspan.*?(.*?)<.*?webbot
```

by

```
startspan -->(.*?)<!--webbot
```

In action:

```
$str = '<!--webbot bot="Include" U-Include="/inspections/Restaurants_Avalon.html" TAG="BODY" startspan --> EVERYTHING IN BETWEEN<!--webbot bot="Include" i-checksum="41417" endspan -->';

$pat = '/<.*?webbot bot=\"Include\" U-Include=\".*?\".*?startspan -->(.*?)<!--webbot bot=\"Include\" i-checksum=\".*?\" endspan.*?/i';

preg_match($pat, $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => <!--webbot bot="Include" U-Include="/inspections/Restaurants_Avalon.html" TAG="BODY" startspan --> EVERYTHING IN BETWEEN<!--webbot bot="Include" i-checksum="41417" endspan
    [1] =>  EVERYTHING IN BETWEEN
)
```

Comment: Didn't work.  Received just an emtpy array back. Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: Also tried: $pattern = '/<!--webbot bot=\"Include\" U-Include=\".*?" TAG=\"BODY\" startspan  -->(.+?)<!--webbot bot=\"Include\" i-checksum=\".*?\" endspan -->/is';

Comment: Just noticed I didn't include the \ in front of a quote. still didn't work when added.

Comment: @ShannonCole: works for me, see my edit. How are you using it?